Askew material added to object
I am new to Blender and I am currently following some YouTube tutorials on how to do different assets, so that I can get some guided hands on practice.
For my present project I am trying to create a lemon and when following the tutorial step by step, when adding the new material that is supposed to be used as the inside, regardless of the image that I am using ( I had a free image with 2 lemons, then one lemon and eventually added a wood texture just to test), I get a slightly askewed view and I am unable to adjust it properly.
I redid the project and used the same tutorial and, again, when I use Project From View I get the same result.
I did try to goole the issue and I ended up thinking it could be 10 dfferent things so that is even more confusing...
Did I mess up the views? I am still struggling with the views and I may have misaligned something... is it because of the shape of the object or the surface and how I filled it?
I decided to ask since for some of you this might be trivial and as I am trying to document I am giving it a shot here.
Here is my result so far.
Blender Version 4.1.1 (4.1.1 2024-04-16)


Where, exactly, is your problem? I can't figure out what's not working right here.

What's your question? If your question is "What did I do wrong?" it's a lot harder to answer than "How do I texture a lemon?" We don't know what you have done, only you know that.

You should really edit this and form a clear and specific question that would describe the goal, the problem and what you would like to know clearly.

hello, we can't see your UV so it's hard to tell if you've correctly unwrapped but maybe share your file? don't forget to pack your image

@dramaticgarlic: hint: if you provide a blend file - people don't have to ask for technical details, you got much more attention and even quicker answers instead of comments.
